# Quantikz horizontal alignment for qwbundle

Tags: quantikz

How can I achieve proper horizontal alignment for the "n" in the MWE?

Couldn't find anything in the docs... https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/graphics/pgf/contrib/quantikz/quantikz.pdf

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$\ket{0}$}&\qwbundle{n}&\gate{U}&\gate{U_a} &\meter{}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this, with some exaggeration?

If so, the key is on p. 18 of the manual "B. Per-Gate Styling". To demonstrate I put the n in red, and shifted it along the x-direction. This package requires some "encapsulation" of tikz-formatting-options: the kind of syntax you'd use when defining own styles etc.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
 \lstick{$\ket{0}$}&\qwbundle{n}&\gate{U}&\gate{U_a} &\meter{}\\
 \lstick{$\ket{0}$}&\qwbundle[style={red,xshift=4mm}]{n}&\gate{U}&\gate{U_a} &\meter{}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, I get a symmetric alignment with `[xshift=2mm]`. Any idea if there's a way to shorten the wire between |0> and the U? Looks like `\qwbundle{}` need it's own `$` delimiters which results in a too long wire for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the follow-up question from a comment.

The best will be to contact the author of the `quantikz` package. To my understanding, the empty space is related to the nodes and grid placement involved. It's not related to the braket characters.

To demonstrate kindly check:

- the outline of the nodes shape
- changes when setting the `inner sep=0`
- limitations imposed by `\lstick` on `label style` formatting, only

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
 \lstick{$\ket{0}$}&\qwbundle{n}&\gate{U}&\gate{U_a} &\meter{}\\
 \lstick{$\ket{0}$}&\qwbundle[style={red,xshift=4mm}]{n}&\gate{U}&\gate{U_a} &\meter{}\\
 \lstick[label style={draw=blue}]{$\alpha$}&\qwbundle[style={red,xshift=2mm}]{n}&\gate{U}&\gate{U_a} &\meter{}\\
  \lstick[label style={inner sep=0mm,draw=blue}]{$\alpha$}&\qwbundle[style={red,xshift=2mm}]{n}&\gate{U}&\gate{U_a} &\meter{}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but I don't think I will pursue this any further.